# Remove breakpoints from the margin in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I often select lines by clicking the line number in the margin in Notepad++ but I often click slightly to the right of the number which sets a breakpoint rather than selecting the line. I never use breakpoints in Notepad++ so I am looking for how to remove breakpoints from the margin so that I don't accidentally click it all the time.

[image: Image of breakpoint in the margin]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Notepad++ has bookmarks, not breakpoints. They're useful sometimes because you can set them and use F2 or Shift+F2 to navigate between them.

You can turn them off in Settings which will remove the column next to the line numbers.

Circa-2020 Versions:

- Settings → Preferences → Editing → uncheck "Display bookmarks"

Circa-2021 Versions:

- Settings → Preferences → Margins/Border/Edge → uncheck "Display bookmark"

Comment: Thanks! Should I change my question to reflect the proper name or should I keep it as-is?

Comment: Probably leave it alone I guess... I'm sure many people think they are breakpoints so then this is easier to find.

Comment: I suggest that this is a flaw in the Notepad++ (NPP) GUI design - a standard visual idiom for breakpoints was used to represent "something else". Now that I know what they are, I may want to change the way I use NPP!

Comment: FYI, in recent versions (v7 maybe?), this "Display bookmarks" option is in Settings -> Preferences -> Margins/Border/Edge.